# Плавный поворот спрайта нужной стороной в сторону движения Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d, спрайт

Уже 3 дня ломаю голову. Есть спрайт самолётика. Двигается по Vector3 вейпоинтам в плоскости (ортографический режим камеры). Как сделать, чтоб он двигался от точки к точке НОСОМ, и поворачивался к следующей точке ПЛАВНО? Перепробовал тучу примеров и инета. Не работает...

Comment: Возможно поможет или подтолкнёт мысль в нужном направлении https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mKLp-2iseDc

Comment: Чувак... ну делал же так вроде... но сейчас заработало! Спасибо!!!